# unable to display a list with alert function

Tags: javascript, list, dom, alert

first post here, i'm trying to write a code following a tutrial, its a to do list and i wrote a function that takes the content of a text type input and adds it to a list, im testing the code using an alert inside the function but it doenst work and no alerts are shown, here's the code. Thanks in advance

```js
let elements = [];
function addElements(){
    if (document.querySelector("#task").nodeValue.trim() != ""){       
        elements.push(document.querySelector("#task").nodeValue.trim())
        alert(elements);
    }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="todoList"></div>
      <form action="#" id="todoForm">
        <label for="task">Task: </label>
        <input type="text" name="task" id="task" autofocus>
        <button class="addBtn">
            <img src="https://upload-icon.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/icons/png/20340289291547546467-64.png" alt="">
        </button>
        <!--<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add To-Do">-->
      </form>
  </div>
  <script src="../todo_list/apps.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: You are not calling `addElements` in any moment. You are just submitting the form.

Comment: i tried calling it after submitting but t doesnt work neither

Comment: Please correct your question with more clear information of what logic  you are  using, what you expect to get and what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So your problem was you didn't call `addElements()` on your button.

and instead of using `nodeValue` just use `value` instead.

this is working code

```js
let elements = [];
function addElements(){
console.log(document.querySelector("#task").value)
    if (document.querySelector("#task").value.trim() != ""){       
        elements.push(document.querySelector("#task").value.trim())
        alert(elements);
    }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="todoList"></div>
      <form action="#" id="todoForm">
        <label for="task">Task: </label>
        <input type="text" name="task" id="task" autofocus>
        <button class="addBtn" onclick="addElements()">
            <img src="https://upload-icon.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/icons/png/20340289291547546467-64.png" alt="">
        </button>
        <!--<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add To-Do">-->
      </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to stop the html form submit with

```
<form action="#" id="todoForm" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Then you need to bind click function to your button, so that when button clicked your `addElements` function will be triggered

```
<button class="addBtn" onclick="addElements()">
```

Finally you need to get the input value with

```
document.getElementById('task').value;
```

### Complete Code Sample

```js
let elements = [];

function addElements() {

  var task = document.getElementById('task').value;

  if (task.trim() != "") {
    elements.push(task);
    alert(elements)
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div id="todoList"></div>

    <form action="#" id="todoForm" onsubmit="return false;">
      <label for="task">Task: </label>
      <input type="text" name="task" id="task" autofocus>
      <button class="addBtn" onclick="addElements()">
        <img src="https://upload-icon.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/icons/png/20340289291547546467-64.png" alt="">
      </button>
    </form>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! his helped me with the issue

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted